# Confusion about the Argument< T > and Variable< T > in .NET 4.0 Workflow Foundation

Tags: .net-4.0, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I am using Windows Workflow Foundation in .NET 4.0. Below is some syntax/semantic confusion I have.

I have 2 equivalent way to declare an Assign activity to assign a value to a workflow **variable** (varIsFreeShipping).

(1) Using XAML in the designer.

[image]

(2) Using code.

[image]

But in approach 2, the it seems I am creating a **new** OutArgument< Boolean > and assign value to it, not to the **original** Variable< Boolean> varIsFreeShipping. And OutArgument and Variable are totally different types.

**So how could the value assigned to this new Argument finally reach the original Variable?**

This pattern seems common in WF 4.0. Could anybody shed some light on this?

Thanks!

Comment: ...After years of such *sub-knowledge*, luckily I am working on something more fundamental.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a matter of fact, the second (2) method can be written just as:

```
Then = new Assign<bool>
{
    To = varIsFreeShipping,
    Value = true
}
```

This all works because [OutArgument<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd485644.aspx) can be initialized through a [Variable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466009.aspx) using an **[implicit operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd484841.aspx)**.

In your first (1) assign, using the editor, that's what's happening behind the scene; the variable is being *implicitly* converted from Variable to OutArgument.

WF4 uses *alot* of implicit operators mainly on Activity<T> from/to Variable<T>, OutArgument<T> from/to Variable<T>, etc. If you look at it, they all represent a piece of data (already evaluated or not), that is located somewhere. It's exactly the same as in C#, for example:

```
public int SomeMethod(int a)
{
    var b = a;
    return a;
}
```

You can assign an argument to a variable, but you can also return that same variable as an *out argument*. That's what you're doing with that Assign<T> activity (using the variable *varIsFreeShipping* as the activity's out argument).

This answers your question?

Comment: Check more about implicit keyword [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can understand the implicit converter operator. My question is **So how could the value assigned to this new Argument finally reach the original Variable?** Can we say that both the argument and the variable are referencing the same piece of memeory under the hood? Because that's the only possible reason I can think of to make this happen.

Comment: Keep in mind that WF is trying to replicate a programming language through which you can execute code giving it all metadata and logic necessary. In this particular case WF has the concept of [Location<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd486266.aspx). More specifically my bet is that OutArgument is using the [VariableReference<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988245.aspx) activity. Both Location and VariableReference try to replicate the concept of *pointers* (a piece of memory somewhere) where all changes made are reflected to the Variables or Arguments pointing to it.

Comment: So when you give OutArgument a Variable it saves its Location (using VariableReference). From then on, when you assign a value to OutArgument in reality you're assigning to a Location reference and not to the Variable itself.

Comment: I agree with you for now. And I will keep digging. Thanks.